# Underscorejs Shuffle with EJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, underscore.js, ejs

Using https://underscorejs.org/#shuffle

Is it possible to use `_.shuffle(list)` with EJS?

**I get _ is not defined.**

`<script type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>`

```
<% var breakfastFoods = []  %>
<% var breakfastFoodsInfo = []  %>
<% for (var food of allDBFoods) { %>
<% if (food.breakfast == true ){ %>
<% breakfastFoods.push(food.name) %>
<% breakfastFoodsInfo.push(food.info) %>
<% } %>
<% } %>


<% _.shuffle([breakfastFoods]); %>
```

Comment: Why don't you install `underscore` with npm and `const _ = require('underscore');` as an example. You should then be able to use in your ejs files. Think this should work

Comment: @Richlewis Hey Rich! I did npm install and required underscore as well. Still can't seem to use it within EJS for some reason

Comment: Check out my answer, hopefully it helps and you can use `underscore` as I use `moment`

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine the process to be similar but this is what I do to use `moment` in my EJS file templates

```
# routes.js

const moment = require('moment');


app.get('/fixtures', (req, res) => {
  const file = await readFile('./views/partials/fixtures.ejs');
  const fixtureTemplate = ejs.compile(file, { client: true });
  const html = fixtureTemplate({ moment });
  res.send({ html });
});
```

In my `examples.ejs` file I can then use moment like so

```
<%=  moment.utc(fixture.kick_off).local().format('HH:mm') %>
```

Hopefully you can follow the same process for using `underscore`

Comment: Thanks @Richlewis! I will give this a try and see how it goes :)